# Why do I need two commas around the "however" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas, prepositional-phrases

In this following sentence, I'm particularly confused with why you would need to have the comma between "out" and "however".

"He found **out, however,** that the public preferred live magic acts to filmed versions.

would the "however" be nonrestrictive?
The previous sentences were:

*Specializing in stage illusions, he thought the camera offered potential to expand his spectacular magic productions. By 1895, he was working with the new invention"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*however* is an interpolation in the simple sentence “*He found out that the public preferred live magic acts to filmed versions.*” The sentence “*He found out however*” is meaningless, and meaning is not added by adding “*, that ...*.”

By inserting the *however* between parenthetical commas, it becomes clear that the word refers not to any part of the sentence, but to a contrast with the preceding sentence.

Comment: Very true, Anton. I don't usually like to equate commas in text with pauses in speech but this is a case where the spoken version backs up what you say. It would be spoken as "He found out <pause> however <pause> that the public preferred live magic acts". Without the pauses the spoken sentence would difficult to understand.

Comment: Including the commas (which are ***only ever*** justified as representing pauses in speech, imho) is a stylistic choice (albeit one that is *usually* made). But there's nothing inherently undesirable in, for example, comma-less [*We discovered however that the cases discussed did not...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=3nWhBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA184&dq=%22discovered+however+that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcvMW-jM3rAhULUBUIHeAhCvQ4HhDoATAAegQIBBAC#v=onepage&q=%22discovered%20however%20that%22&f=false)